# how to create an alias for sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, url

we have this long url for our sharepoint online. https://xxcompany0xx.sharepoint.com

How are we able to change this site url fqdn to be shorter and easier to reminder..

eg

https://ourcompany.sharepoint.com etc or something...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the prefix is based solely on the O365 tenant DNS name and cannot be changed/aliased.  E.g. .onmicrosoft.com

You're only option is to set up a web server on a FQDN you own and do a HTTP redirect to your environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the tenant name as yet.  You can register your voice here.  https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273493-office-365-admin/suggestions/10285887-make-is-possible-to-change-tenant-name-in-office36?page=1&per_page=20.

You can see further information about Office 365 domains here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Domains-FAQ-1272bad0-4bd4-4796-8005-67d6fb3afc5a

and SharePoint URL : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Can-t-rename-a-SharePoint-team-site-576325ad-8c40-4fe8-8a63-68c3b7d536cf?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US